# POST buffer data in Node.js

Tags: node.js, rest, request, buffer

I'm interested in posting image data (stored on Amazon S3) to a REST endpoint.  The image data appears to be returned as buffer:

```
var request = require('request');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

s3.getObject({Bucket: bucket, Key: key}, function(err, data) {
  console.log(data.Body);
  // <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 ...
```

When I try and upload the buffer using the request library:

```
  request.post('https://example.com', {'upload_file': data.Body});
```

It explodes, since it's apparently attempting to URI encode it:

```
/node_modules/request/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:40
        return [encodeURIComponent(prefix) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj)];
                                                   ^
URIError: URI malformed
    at encodeURIComponent (native)
    at Object.internals.stringify (/node_modules/request/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:40:52)
    at Object.module.exports [as stringify] (/node_modules/request/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:93:38)
    at Request.form (/node_modules/request/request.js:1320:20)
    at Request.init (/node_modules/request/request.js:503:10)
    at new Request (/node_modules/request/request.js:272:8)
    at request (/node_modules/request/index.js:56:10)
```

Comment: I don't think this is supported by the request module.  You may want to try sending it with the builtin http module instead.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by moving to the 'restler' NPM package and using a (sadly) undocumented feature.  So the following:

```
request.post('https://example.com', {'upload_file': data.Body});
```

Became:

```
s3.getObject({Bucket: bucket, Key: key}, function(err, data) {
  var form = {
    file_name: key,
    upload_file: rest.data(key, data.ContentType, data.Body)
  };
  var opts = {
    data: form,
    multipart: true
  };  
  rest.post('example.com', opts).on('complete', function(results, response) {
    //...handle success
  })
});
```